# Tally is lagging till the time response comes

Tags: xml, postman, response, httpresponse, tally

When ever I am hitting XML code for fetching some data from tally then my tally is lagging till the time the response comes. How do I fix the problem ?

I am hitting the xml code in postman till the time response comes my tally is not responsing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thats how tally works,
there is nothing we can do.
We can request small chunks of data to make sure tally doesn't go not responding state permanently.